# Set Default Entry Types for elements in a Structure Section

Tags: structure, sections, entry-type

I have a Structure Section controlling my Nav and page contents
So I have

Home

About Us

- History
- List item
- List item

Services

- Service 1
- Service 2
- Service 3

In the Control Panel when I add items to this structure I have 3 different Entry Types.
Is it possible to set it so that when I add a Child to the Services structure item a specific entry type can be set as default as opposed to the first one?

Or should create a different structure section for each one and have its own entry type?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if you can set a default entry type within Craft.

But a reasonably workaround would be to go to Settings > Sections, then click 'Edit entry types' for the section you need to apply this to. Next, drag the entry type you would like to be used by default to the top of the entry-type list.

That way, when a new entry is added to the Section, the default entry type will be whichever type is the top of the list.

Hope this helps, but as I say there may be some other answers that offer a cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks - yep it is possible to set a default by dragging it top of the entry list. I was wondering was it possible to set a different default for different levels of the structure - but from what I see it doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: @mmc501 No it isn't possible to set defaults for each level, I'm afraid you can only 'set' one default entry type for the entire structure. That is the best you can do with the core functionality of Craft, but a custom plugin may be able to help you out here.